# querying a function that returns record in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How do I see the values returned by a function that returns record datatype ?
Here is the function

```
TYPE employee_record_info IS RECORD (
employee_id NUMBER,
employee_name VARCHAR2(100),
manager_id NUMBER,
location VARCHAR2(100)
);

FUNCTION function1(in_employee_id NUMBER) RETURN employee_record_info AS
    l_record employee_record_info;
    BEGIN
        SELECT employee_id, employee_name, manager_id, location 
        INTO
        l_record
        FROM all_employees where employee_id = in_employee_id;       
    RETURN l_record;
    END function1;
```

I tried

```
select * from table(function1(123));
```

and

```
select function1(123) from dual;
```

I am getting invalid type error in both cases ? Is there a way to get these values.
I just need this to test my function and this is not for using in any code.

Also need some help in the case where function is returning array please.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us your function definition

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 4):

Your code is for pl/sql, you won't be able to use SQL to select.  You could rewrite it to make it workable for SQL selects, something like:

```
SQL> create or replace type emp_rec_typ as object(
employee_id NUMBER,
employee_name VARCHAR2(100),
manager_id NUMBER,
location VARCHAR2(100)
);
Type created.
SQL> create or replace type emp_tab_typ as table of emp_rec_typ;
Type created.
SQL> create or replace function get_emps
return emp_tab_typ
as
    emps emp_tab_typ := emp_tab_typ();
begin
    select emp_rec_typ(x.employee_id, x.employee_name, x.manager_id, x.location) 
    bulk collect into emps
    from (
        select 1 as employee_id, 'Joe Blow' as employee_name, 1 as manager_id, 'Some Place' as location from dual
        union all
        select 2 as employee_id, 'Jane Doe' as employee_name, 1 as manager_id, 'Some Other Place' as location from dual
        union all
        select 3 as employee_id, 'Fred Smith' as employee_name, 2 as manager_id, 'Some Strange Place' as location from dual
    ) x;

    return emps;

end;
Function created.
SQL> select * from table(get_emps);

EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOYEE_NAME   MANAGER_ID  LOCATION
1   'Joe Blow'  1   'Some Place'
2   'Jane Doe'  1   'Some Other Place'
3   'Fred Smith'    2   'Some Strange Place'
```